# How to create a menu when a user right-clicks on the dock-icon of cocoa app on Mac?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

How to create a menu when a user right-clicks on the dock-icon of cocoa app on Mac?

Thank you very much in advance!

Max

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Implement [`applicationDockMenu:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) in your app delegate to return the menu you want to use.

Comment: that’s the simplest way

Answer (score 2):

Or, in MainMenu.xib, create an NSMenu instance and connect it to your NSApplication's `dockMenu` outlet.